# WRT54GS with Tomato 1.28 and StrongVPN - I want to exclude Torrent and Voip from VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn

As the title says, I have a strongvpn on a wrt54gs with tomato and I want to pass most traffic to vpn except for torrent and voip.  How can I do that please?

Although there are some similar discussions in other forums but if anything specific to wrt54gs and strongvpn is very much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no application-dependent routing.

There are solutions, but they are complex and partial. Basically, you can have an interface-dependent routing table (called policy routing). That means: create a new, virtual interface, route traffic reaching this interface with a routing table different from the standard one, and have VoIp and torrent application send traffic to this interface.

Many pieces of this are discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/702394/can-i-do-policy-routing-on-a-virtual-interface). You will then have to learn how to bind an application to a given interface. That can be done in Linux, see [here](http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html), not in Mac Os nor Windows.

Alternatively you may:

1. Put the OpenVPN client on a pc on your LAN;
2. Indicate that pc as the gateway for all the other pcs on the LAN, so that all communication is forced through the VPN;
3. leave one pc, from which you start torrent and VoIP applications, with your Tomato router as a gateway. This way, this particular pc will never go through the VPN.

A variation of this would be to have *two* routers, a Tomato like you already have and another not acting as a client to any VPN. Then the first reference tells you to access one or the other, depending on need.